# Python: Convert utf-8 string to byte string

Tags: python, string, encoding, utf-8

I have the following function to parse a utf-8 string from a sequence of bytes

Note -- 'length_size' is the number of bytes it take to represent the length of the utf-8 string

```
def parse_utf8(self, bytes, length_size):

    length = bytes2int(bytes[0:length_size])
    value = ''.join(['%c' % b for b in bytes[length_size:length_size+length]])
    return value


def bytes2int(raw_bytes, signed=False):
    """
    Convert a string of bytes to an integer (assumes little-endian byte order)
    """
    if len(raw_bytes) == 0:
        return None
    fmt = {1:'B', 2:'H', 4:'I', 8:'Q'}[len(raw_bytes)]
    if signed:
        fmt = fmt.lower()
    return struct.unpack('<'+fmt, raw_bytes)[0]
```

I'd like to write the function in reverse -- i.e. a function that will take a utf-8 encoded string and return it's representation as a byte string.

So far, I have the following:

```
def create_utf8(self, utf8_string):
    return utf8_string.encode('utf-8')
```

I run into the following error when attempting to test it:

```
  File "writer.py", line 229, in create_utf8
return utf8_string.encode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

If possible, I'd like to adopt a structure for the code similar to the parse_utf8 example. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help!

**UPDATE: test driver, now correct**

```
def random_utf8_seq(self, length):
    # from http://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/postscript-utf-8.html
    test_charset = u" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­ ®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿĂăĄąĆćČčĎďĐđĘęĚěĹĺĽľŁłŃńŇňŐőŒœŔŕŘřŚśŞşŠšŢţŤťŮůŰűŸŹźŻżŽžƒˆˇ˘˙˛˜˝–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›€™"

    utf8_seq = u""

    for i in range(length):
        utf8_seq += random.choice(test_charset)

    return utf8_seq
```

I get the following error:

```
input_str = self.random_utf8_seq(200)
  File "writer.py", line 226, in random_utf8_seq
print unicode(utf8_seq, "utf-8")
  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: The code here is vastly more complex than justified, and suggests numerous misconceptions. The built-in `.encode` and `.decode` methods are for this. The reason for the original error in the test driver is that **not all sequences of bytes are valid UTF-8 data**. The way this post was updated causes it to make no sense for future viewers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If utf-8 => bytestring conversion is what do you want then you may use `str.encode`, but first you need to properly mark the type of source string in your example - prefix with `u` for unicode:

```
# coding: utf-8
import random

    def random_utf8_seq(length):
        # from http://www.w3.org/2001/06/utf-8-test/postscript-utf-8.html
        test_charset = u" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­ ®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿĂăĄąĆćČčĎďĐđĘęĚěĹĺĽľŁłŃńŇňŐőŒœŔŕŘřŚśŞşŠšŢţŤťŮůŰűŸŹźŻżŽžƒˆˇ˘˙˛˜˝–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›€™"

        utf8_seq = u''

        for i in range(length):
            utf8_seq += random.choice(test_charset)

        print utf8_seq.encode('utf-8')
        return utf8_seq.encode('utf-8')

    print( type(random_utf8_seq(200)) )
```

-- output --
­

```
õ3×sÔP{Ć.s(Ë°˙ě÷xÓ@bűV—û´ő¢uZÓČn˜0|_"Ðyø`êš·ÏÝhunÍÅ=ä?
óP{tlÇűpb¸7s´ňƒG—čøň\zčłŢXÂYqLĆúěă(ÿî ¥PyÐÔŇn×œ¦Ì˝+•ì›
ŻÛ°Ñ^ÝC÷ŢŐIñJĹţÒył­"MťÆ‹ČČ4þ!»šåŮ@Öhň-
ÈLGĄ¢ß˛Đ¯.ªÆź˘Ř^ĽÛŹËaĂŕ¹#¢éüÜńlÊqš=VřU…‚–MŽÎÉèoÙŹŠ¨Ð
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: That did it, thank you! In the end, my string generation driver was incorrect, as you suggested